# Android app that can connect to my phone via Bluetooth, making/receiving calls, with contact list & call record

Tags: bluetooth, android-app, remote-control, car

Android head units for cars usually have installed an Android app which can connect to your phone via Bluetooth.
This app is used to initiate calls in 3 ways:

1. by providing a dial pad
2. by presenting the call records pulled from the phone
3. by presenting the contacts list pulled from the phone

It is also used for receiving calls. Whenever a call comes in on your phone, the app pops up on the Android head unit presenting the user with options whether to accept or reject the call. When accepting the call, the audio is transferred to the Android app via Bluetooth and then routed to the car speakers.

Usually, when you pair the Android head unit with your phone, the device appears in your phone's BT paired devices list and is given authorization for certain uses. These uses can be toggled ON/OFF with the available toggle buttons. These uses usually consist of:

1. Calls
2. Audio
3. Contact Access

Every car manufacturer using Android devices in their cars has one of these apps. Also, most aftermarket Android head units implement such apps in their solutions. Furthermore, all Android watches implement such apps in them.

I am looking for one such application, as described in detail above, that is freely available for purchase & download.

Comment: Its usually best to ask what you are trying to do, instead of deciding on a solution and then asking questions.  Are you looking for a hands free solution for calls (and maps)

Comment: "I am looking for one such application, as described in detail above, that is freely available for purchase & download." because my current app does not implement audio routing correctly. It routes audio to device speakers when there is a USB DAC connected.

Comment: Have you checked if "USB audio pass-through" is enabled/disabled in your DevOps?  If this setting isn't available on the frontend, you may need to use, e.g., [SetEdit](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=setedit&c=apps) to modify the behavior.

Comment: Are you talking about "Disable USB audio routing"? This option exists in my list and it is OFF. Thus my USB audio routing is not disabled. Is this what you were talking about?